# How to fetch data only once in a Next.js app and make it accesible to all the app, both in server and client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a Next.js app that needs to fetch a config file from a remote server before initializing. I want to request the config file just once per call to the server before rendering the app server side. After that, I would like to be able to get the same config in the client without having to make a second request to the remote server from the browser.

I have tried to achieve this by using `getInitialProps` function either in `_app` or `_document` files and then use the React's Context API to make the configuration visible to every component but unless I'm wrong, this will run the code that requests the configuration both in server (on the first call from the browser) and client (on every page navigation).

I have also tried to create a server.js file, request the configuration from there and store in a variable within a ES6 module. However, I couldn't make this approach work because apparently the Next.js React app can't access the same modules than the server.js because they are actually two different apps. Again, I could be wrong.

Basically I would like to know if Next.js offers any kind of "bootstrapping place" where I can perform app initialization tasks that generate data that can be sent to the React app Next.js will initiate.

Comment: Did you get to finally solve the problem? I'm in need of doing the same thing? Cn you share how did you accomplish this?

Comment: Hi @JithinKs, I added an answer with a mitigation solution. Probably not the best approach. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct in that anything in `getInitialProps` in `_app.js` or `_document.js` will be run on every server request. Once you get your config, you can pass it down to the components in `pages` as props. From there, I think you have two choices:

1. Now that the app is bootstrapped, run the rest of the app as a SPA client-side. This would prevent any future SSR from happening. Obviously, you lose the benefits of SSR and the initial page load is likely longer, but then it would be snappy afterwards.
2. After getting the config in `_app.js`, send it as a cookie (assuming it's not too big to be a cookie?). On future requests to the server, the cookie will be sent automatically and you would check the cookie first - if it doesn't exist, get the config. If it does exist, skip that more expensive bootstrapping because the app is bootstrapped.

So I think it really depends on whether you want a single page application bootstrapped on the server but then entirely client side after that (option 1) or server side rendering per page while minimizing expensive bootstrapping (option 2).

Nothing prevents you from sending multiple cookies from the server if that makes sense for your app and bootstrapping. And remember **not** to make it a HTTP-Only cookie because you'll want to read that cookie client side - after all, that's what you're looking for - the client side configuration generated on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My case is number one, a server side rendered app that becomes a SPA after the first load. After investigating a bit more I saw that _document is only rendered once on the server while _app is rendered once on server side plus every time there is a navigation on the client side.
This makes me think the best place for initial app data gathering is actually _document, is this what you were suggesting? If it is, what's the way to pass all the data received in the app initialization as props to the rest of the app?

Comment: Then you probably don’t even need SSR and next. You can achieve this with create-React-app and serve it with a configuration cookie like #1 using an express server to host it. Any request to the server - and for your users, that’s just the initial one - can run the config via node and send that along with your app down the pipe. After that, SPA takes over entirely.

Comment: I do need SSR actually, that's a requirement for us so we need to at least be able to serve the first hit rendered on server side, and that is what made us decide to use Next. Having said this, after the first hit and as you say, the React app takes over at client side and the app becomes a normal SPA, that's fine for us too. What we are trying so far is to get the config at server side and somehow make it part of the react data so that once in the client it gets recreated and it's available for the app on the browser. With no success for now :(

Answer (score 5):

Despite we ended up leaving Next.js for this and other reasons that made us decide Next.js was not the best option for our use case, we kind of mitigated this problem as follows while be sticked to it, I hope it makes sense to anyone. Also, by now maybe Next.js provides a better way to do this so I would read the Next.js docs before using my approach. Final note: I don't have access to the code anymore since I change to a different company so maybe there are some points that won't be 100% as we made it.

There is goes:

1. We created a module that was responsible to request the config file and keep the results in a variable. At the moment of importing this module, we ensure that the variable is not already present in window.`__NEXT_DATA__`. If it is, we recover it, if it's not, we request it to the remote server (this will be helpful in the clint side rendering).
2. We created a `server.js` file as [described by Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server). In this file we make the call to get the config file and store it in memory.
3. In the body of the function passed to `createServer` we add the config file into the `req` object to make it accesible to the app in the `getInitialProps` functions server side.
4. We made sure that the getInitialProps using the config file returns it, so that it will be passed to the components as props and also serialized by Next.js and made available to the client in the `__NEXT_DATA__` global Javascript variable.
5. Given that the config ended up in the `__NEXT_DATA__` variable in the server, using the trick described in the step 1 makes the app not request the config for a second time.